# Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE

Tags: python, pygame

When messing around with example files in the pygame download, I ran a program (untouched) and an error message popped up saying that the symbol _SDL_EnableUNICODE was not found. What does the symbol do and how can I get around it or obtain the symbol?

Error Message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lukecat2883/Downloads/pygame-1.9.3/examples/macosx/aliens_app_example/aliens.py", line 6, in 
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/**init**.py", line 133, in 
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): Symbol not found: _SDL_EnableUNICODE
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so

Comment: It also says that the symbol is expected in a "flat namespace"

Comment: Please provide more information. Post the whole error message, tell us the name of the example file and what operating system, Python and pygame version you use.

Comment: osx el capitan, python 2.7.13 (32-bit),

Comment: How did you install pygame?

Comment: first from the site, then by pip install on terminal.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but many people have trouble installing pygame on Macs. Perhaps SDL isn't installed correctly which pygame uses under the hood. Could you try to install Python 3 and then `pip3 install pygame` to see if it works better with this Python version?

Comment: I emailed the creators of pygame to see if they know. but thanks anyway

Comment: YW. You can answer your own question when you've figured this out to help others with the same problem.